# Wordpress - Error: Options Page Not Found

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I know there's a few solutions out there for this problem, but none of them seem to fix my code.

I've been following a lynda.com tutorial on creating plugins. However I believe they are using an older version of wordpress, which is why I think I'm running into trouble.

I'm trying to add an options page, but everytime I "save" on my options page it gives me "not found" error for the options.php page.

- Tried linking to options.php directly (with full URL), no dice.
- Tried changing register_setting to both equal the same thing, as stated in Wordpress Codex, but that didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
function cc_init(){
    register_setting('cc_options,','cc_cc_email');
}add_action('admin_init','cc_init');


function cc_option_page(){
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <?php screen_icon(); ?>
    <h2>CC Comments Options</h2>
    <p>Welcome to the CC comments plugin. here you can edit the email(s) to CC your comments to.</p>
    <form action="options.php" method="post" id="cc-comments-email-options-form">
    <?php settings_fields('cc_options'); ?>
    <h3><label for="cc_cc_email">Eamil to send CC to:</label>
    <input type="text" id="cc_cc_email" name="cc_cc_email" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('cc_cc_email')); ?>" /></h3>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Email" /></p>    
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function cc_plugin_menu(){
    add_options_page('CC Comments Settings','CC Comments','manage_options','cc-comments-plugin','cc_option_page');
}add_action('admin_menu','cc_plugin_menu');
```

Comment: The third argument to add_options_page() should be path to plugin option file. Checkout http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page for details.

Comment: As far as I can tell on that page, the third argument is supposed to be the $capability of the plugin, as on this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities
my third argument is the same as the examples. I'm not sure what you mean by "path to plugin option file".

Answer (score 0):

I think I had my add_action('admin_menu', 'cc_plugin_menu'); in the wrong spot. I moved it into the cc_plugin_menu function and it seems to save OK now.

Here's the updated code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'cc_plugin_menu');

function register_mysettings() {
    register_setting( 'cc_options', 'cc_cc_email' );
}

function cc_option_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h2>CC Comments Options</h2>
    <p>Welcome to the CC comments plugin. here you can edit the email(s) to CC your comments to.</p>
    <form method="post" action="options.php" id="cc-comments-email-options-form">
        <?php settings_fields( 'cc_options' ); ?>
        <?php do_settings_sections( 'cc_options' ); ?>
        <h3><label for="cc_cc_email">Eamil to send CC to:</label>
        <input type="text" id="cc_cc_email" name="cc_cc_email" 
                value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('cc_cc_email')); ?>" /></h3>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Email" /></p>    
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php 
} 

function cc_plugin_menu(){
    add_options_page('CC Comments Settings','CC Comments','manage_options','cc-comments-plugin','cc_option_page');
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );
}
```